# Change direction of negative number with combination of LTR and RTL content

Tags: html, css, bidi

Here is my HTML structure:

```css
div{
  direction: rtl;
}

span{
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>امروز -2</span>
  </div>
```

This is expected result:

[image]

As you see, `-` sign should come in the beginning of the number. How can I do that?

**Note:** The direction of `div` should be `rtl`.

---

**ٍEDIT:** I generate that number like this:

```
$sums_value = sprintf("%+d",$sums_value);

/* 
sums_value = -2 //=> -2
sums_value = 2  //=> +2
```

So the number has right format, but I don't know why it will be broken in the output:

[image]

Comment: It's probably treating `-2` as one item, so it's not reversing it. Just write the number normally in the markup.

Comment: I know this is probably painfully obvious, but is there no reason you can simply write it in the ltr format? (Is it dynamic content?)

Comment: @Carcigenicate The number is written normally in the markup. As you see it is `-5` in the inspect element box. But I don't know why it will be reverse in the website like `5-` ...

Comment: @DBS Yeah it is a dynamic content.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since your screenshot has the "-2" in a different `span` element you could is the `unicode-bidi` option on that specific span:

```css
div{
  direction: rtl;
}

span{
  direction: ltr;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

```html
<div>
  امروز 
  <span>-2</span>
</div>
```

> The general idea of `unicode-bidi` is to have the ability to change the default behavior of directionality of the text where you have multiple languages on the same page.

Since you are using an `RTL` language, and you want the `-2` to appear in `LTR`, the `unicode-bidi: bidi-override` is very handy.

Comment: Excellent .. upvote ... You know, I never seen `unicode-bidi` so far .. well played ..!

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me:

```
span {
  unicode-bidi: plaintext;
}
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi

By the way, 'bidi' is short for bidirectional.

Comment: @A.J. good point about it not working in Safari; I hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [before pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to add a hyphen.

```
q::before { 
  content: "-";
  color: blue;
}


<q>Some quotes</q>, he said.
```

Will render as

```
-Some quotes, he said.
```